# JS: Memorizing theme with JS & CSS theme switcher

Tags: javascript

I have a little problem, I've made a Javascript theme switcher with buttons, but the problem is that the selected design isn't saved so the users have to change it each time, how can I store the user's choice? Here is my code (i have 5 themes):

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName('theme');
const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');

Array.from(radios).forEach((el, i) => {
  el.addEventListener('change', e => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      let value = e.target.getAttribute('value');
      document.querySelector('html').setAttribute('data-theme', value);
      document.documentElement.classList.add('in-transition')
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        document.documentElement.classList.remove('color-theme-in-transition')
      }, 1000)

    }
  });
});
```

I've tried to mix my code with this one which stores the data but can't manage to have something working

```
const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]');
const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');

if (currentTheme) {
  document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', currentTheme);

  if (currentTheme === 'dark') {
    toggleSwitch.checked = true;
  }
}

function switchTheme(e) {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
    localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');
  } else {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
    localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');
  }
}

toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', switchTheme, false);
```

Comment: Your second snippet works. See: https://jsfiddle.net/kw3otx4g/

Comment: Hello, thank you ! The issue with these codes is that there are only two themes wereas the actual one have five, so I want to make the same thing on the second (which works) on the first one (which i need to use) !